# Red marks on turtle shell

Tags: turtles, wound-care

[image]Red marks on Indian Flapshell turtle shell and rough shell instead of a smooth shell like normal flapshell turtle shells. Thso problem is there with it for 2 to 3 months. I thought they would become normal but they just remained there.

I give it no supplements, it just feeds on tomatoes, potato and fishes. It is kept for about 3 to 4 hours in clean fresh water in a tub kept in late morning sunlight and gets all day at the corner of the open roof where I have kept moist soil and lots of hay. Since last year it had not grown much but is active and healthy. Last year it shed its shell's upper skin and new fresh skin came but this problem has occurred within these few months and is increasing consistently. I don't think we have a turtle vet nearby. What to do?

Comment: do you give your turtle any suplements like minerals and vitamins,do your turtle get natural sunlight during the day?

Comment: What is the setting your turtle lives in? What do you do for clean water? What light source is there? Do you have a basking area (island where the turtle can dry)? How fast was it growing the last year? Has the shell soft spots?

Comment: I am sorry, I m no expert in turtles with soft shell. I can imagine three options: infection, hurted skin or failed shedding. Infection could be caused, if the shell should once a day get dry, but is not (in hard shell turtles it should dry once a day). Hurted skin could be the case if there is some sharp edge inside the enclosure, the turtle scraps over/on regularly. Or the shedding thing, if it should shed each year, may occure by impropper food and sun, so the uppest skin can not deconnect from the lower skin. Maybe you should research this options at a website you trust for soft turtles